# Is there a script code in Google Sheets to repeat a tax/formula everyday at the same time?

Tags: google-sheets

sorry if there's something wrong. My english is not that good and I'm not a developer. I use a Google Sheet to organize my money and I have a bank account that updates everyday with a tax that goes 1,00003%.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHNhT.jpg)

```
=(E1-D1)*1,00003
```

The formula is very basic but it works like I need. So, **my problem is that this formula needs to update everyday with the new value, at a specific time, without entering in the spreadsheet.** I have some experience with Google Script, but I can't figure this out.

I already thought about getting the API of the bank, but they didn't publish it yet.

Example: 1.017,14 will be 1.017,17 tomorrow (04/29), but without the need to enter the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

That will run your Apps Script function automatically every day at the desired time.

Now the function itself which will run on trigger, should look something like

```
function myFunction(){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('PASTE HERE NAME OF SHEET');
   var cell = sheet.getRange("A1"); // or any other cell of interest
   E1 = sheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
   D1 = sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
   cell.setValue((E1-D1)*1,00003);
}
```

Please note that this is only a sample and I strongly encourage you to get familiar with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to understand this code and adapt it to your needs.